# How to use the pgfmanual package to document packages in tikz-style

Tags: tikz-pgf, documentation

I love the way tikz's (and tizk-cd's) documentation is formatted with clickable links to go to the definition of a style/command, colors, examples with image and code next to each others etc… As mentionned here [Package to obtain the style of the TikZ/PGF-Documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554726/package-to-obtain-the-style-of-the-tikz-pgf-documentation) pgfmanual seems to provide such functionalities but has not been documented.

Would it be possible to have  quick introduction to how to use `pgfmanual`, together with pointers to explore more advanced options?

Comment: See *1.5 Authors and Acknowledgements* in the packages documentation. Manual use (as well all other similar LaTeX documents with hyper text facility) `hyperref` package for this.

Comment: @Zarko : thanks, but I don't see how this acknowledgement is helping, it is just a list of people. And I huess hyperref is used internally, but I guess other mechanisms are involved to automatically add links to code… It would be way too tedious to do it manually.

Comment: In Acknowledgement is clearly stated who add hypertext to manual. Yes, this is demanding manual task. you need to insert ˙`hyperref`  anchoes.  In this can be of help editor. Ho to do this, see documentation for `hyperref` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a minimal example for how to use the PGF manual style.  Note the following requirements

1. You *must* use the `ltxdoc` documentclass.
2. The packages `calc`, `tikz` and `hyperref` are required.
3. The “optional” argument of `codeexample` is not really optional. Even if it is empty, there have to be empty brackets `[]`.

I recommend using the `hidelinks` option for `hyperref` to hide the red boxes around links in the PDF.  In general the `hyperref` package should be loaded as late as possible (see also [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before)).

Since PGF 3.1.6 the file `pgfmanual-en-macros.tex` is installed into the TeX search path. Before that version you have to go to the PGF documentation directory and copy the file into your working directory.

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\input{pgfmanual-en-macros.tex}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{command}{\textbf\marg{text}}
  Prints its argument in bold.
  % These empty brackets are NOT optional
  %                |
  %                v
\begin{codeexample}[]
\textbf{This is a test}
\end{codeexample}
  %
\end{command}

\begin{environment}{{center}}
  Center text horizontally on the page.
  %
\begin{codeexample}[vbox]
  \begin{center}
    \textbf{This is a test}
  \end{center}
\end{codeexample}
  %
\end{environment}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If for some reason you want to document starred commands separately with the `command` environment, see [this workaround](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/830#issuecomment-635688746).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to compile this example but it gives `ERROR: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/codeexample/prettyprint/comment font', to which you passed '\itshape ', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`. Any idea what's wrong? Also, I'm curious, what's the link between `pgfmanual-en-macros.tex` and `pgfmanual`?

Comment: So I managed to make this code work by copying this folder https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/tree/247f1f0445a9e996560c9f5a9b3fb03a4184e6ec/tex/latex/pgf/doc onto the working directory. I'm not sure why because I'm on a quite recent TeX distribution (TexLive 2021, Tikz/pgf version 3.1.8b). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, for example on how to add environments with optional arguments, see https://github.com/astoff/tikz-cd/blob/c1eb4c96291b48a4a7f9f348b2e22473dd48de3d/tikz-cd-doc.tex#L227

Comment: Also a question: how can I use environments like `\begin{center} \end{center}` or `itemize` inside a `codeexample`? They all fail.

Comment: @tobiasBora You can't. `pgfmanual-en-macros.tex` was designed to only work for the purposes of the PGF manual. There is zero support for any other use-case.

Comment: Ok thanks. That said, I found an example that was using the pre and post arguments to insert a minipage around the code… it may be enough? Also, any idea how I could force the code to be on a different line that the picture? Sometimes it does it automatically (even if code fits on the right) but sometimes it does not (even if the code goes inside the margin).

Comment: @tobiasBora To typeset examples that need a paragraph, use the `vbox` option (see updated answer).  To break all codeexamples use `\pgfkeys{/codeexample/every codeexample/.append style={width=0pt}}`.  As you can see the options get more and more obscure. That's because there is **absolutely no support!**

Comment: Thanks a lot! Too bad this library is not supported, it's just great!